# Presenter Tools vs Slideshow Notebook?

Tags: notebooks, slideshows

I typically use [slides.com](http://slides.com) for my presentations (which is essentially a web interface for building reveal.js slideshows).  Now, I'm attempting to try out the *Wolfram Presenter Tools* (new in v11.3) which seems to be just a slower version of the old slideshow notebook.

The issue for me is that using the presenter tools template is difficult due to very low frame rates (it just feels a bit bloated).  For example, if I try to resize the window and move the mouse slowly, the frontend can't resize the window smoothly:

[image]

I tried to see if notebooks made with Presenter Tools would smartly scale graphics and figures as zoom factor and window sizes change - *and it doesn't*.

There are lots of little problems too, i.e. if you try to resize the slider in the "outline pallette" with page thumbnails turned on, the frontend freezes:

[image]

So I don't see any real benefits here (still no nice slide transitions, in-place videos, or object reveals), what am I missing?

**Links:**

- Wolfram blog [post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2018/04/19/five-ways-to-make-your-technical-presentations-awesome/)
- Docs on [presenter tools](http://www.wolfram.com/presenter-tools/)

Comment: New features start at 4:30 I think: https://youtu.be/eklh0FOgvwQ?t=269

Comment: The side-code feature seems somewhat useful

Comment: @M.R. I also thought so, but the side-code window is also visible in the beamer view, which somehow defats the purpose I would say.

Comment: I am still looking for somebodywho knows how to format the slides with full-screen background images.

Comment: @MarkusRoellig the setting is `BackgroundAppearance`. Look at the stylesheets of some of the old slideshow templates.

Comment: All my Mathematica windows are like that when they have some content.

Comment: Anyone know how to animate in bulletpoints or graphic elements?